# Datatable .visible() não funciona

Tags: angularjs, datatable

Estou usando esta biblioteca [angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/api), mas a função `visible` não está ocultando as colunas desejadas ao carregar a página.

Segue o código que deveria ocultar as colunas:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var column = $('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable().columns([1,2,3]).visible(false);
});
```

Comment: Você está usando em Angular? Essa função é jQuery, você está usando ambos?

Comment: Sim, estou usando ambos. Mas se eu criar uma função e chamar ela no click por exemplo também não funciona.